# What to do with derived font name longer than 29 characters?

Tags: fonts, installing, minionpro

When installing the MinionPro package from ctan I receive the following error after running the convert.sh script:

```
Creating PostScript fonts ...
warning: derived font name ‘MinionPro-SemiboldCnItCaptLCDFJ’ longer than 29   characters
(Use the ‘--name’ option to supply your own name.)
warning: derived font name ‘MinionPro-SemiboldCnItDispLCDFJ’ longer than 29 characters
(Use the ‘--name’ option to supply your own name.)
warning: derived font name ‘MinionPro-SemiboldCnItSubhLCDFJ’ longer than 29 characters
(Use the ‘--name’ option to supply your own name.)
```

What is the appropriate way do handle this error? I have also tried the FontPro package from https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro and it results in the same message.

Comment: Why don't you use `XeTeX` or `LuaTeX`?

Comment: I need to use ClassicThesis and it does not like it when I try and load fontspec. I am sorry i did not post that in the actual question. Forr some reason I can not edit my question anymore.

Comment: @dfc Are you able to edit the question in order to state it more clearly?

Comment: Can we reopen this? I get the same warning when creating Minion fonts using FontPro (for (pdf)TeX). Can't TeX handle font names longer than 29 characters? Can one safely ignore this warning? Should I have renamed the .otf files first?